# Does this type of chinese pop have a genre name?

Tags: identify-this-genre, genre-characteristics, k-pop, asian

Youtube got me hooked on a particular style of chinese pop music compilation videos lately. [Here is one example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdvYtqI9lMQ), but there seem to be hundreds with mostly the same songs.

I find it great as background music while working, even though (or perhaps because) I don't understand a word of it.

I'm curious if this type of music belongs to a particular genre, and if so, which? It doesn't quite seem like pop/C-Pop. But it seems many of the songs have some particular characteristics in common, even though  I can't really put my finger on it. I guess my best shot would be to describe it as "very melodic and slick/processed pop-power-ballads"...

Answer (score 1):

As the title of this video is, it is a compilation of ballad CPOP. As far as I know there is not a specific genre for such works besides 'CPOP' and 'ballad', however, I recognized there are some house elements in these songs and supposed that was the reason why it gave a background music vibe to you. I recommend to check progressive house or deep house music in Youtube which are very good background music materials as well.